# How do I log into my Linux laptop if I have forgotten both the login and password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, password

How do I log into my Linux laptop if I have forgotten both the username and password?

Comment: What Linux flavor is it? Do you know what the boot-loader (Grub or Lilo) is?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 9.04 server, 2.6.28.18. Has GRUB v 0.97

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can drop into single mode from Grub. During boot press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the Grub boot screen when it prompts you to. It may just show you Grub with listings of each kernel - if that's the case don't press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

From here select the first entry and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit that entry. Page down to the line that starts with `kernel` and press <kbd>e</kbd> again.

This will allow you to edit the entire line. Scroll to the right until you reach the end and remove `splash quiet` from the line, replacing it with `single`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the changes and press <kbd>b</kbd> to boot into the modified kernel line. This will boot you into single user mode and should drop you into a root shell once the boot has completed.

From here you can add users to the system, change user passwords, etc.

Comment: +1 A much better answer than what I was going to suggest.

Comment: If the above fails -- unlikely if GRUB is password -- boot from an Ubuntu livecd (preferrably 9.04 server), mount your Ubuntu partitions, then `chroot` into it.  You can then issue the `passwd` command to reset root, your user, etc.

Answer (score 10):

You might do as [Marco suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/how-do-i-log-into-my-linux-laptop-if-i-have-forgotten-both-the-login-and-password/17842#17842), but his will not work on all distros. More precisely, *it will not work without the need of giving the root password* on systems using openrc.

The more generic way, without using any other bootable media, is to append `init=/bin/bash` or `init=/bin/sh` to boot options (that's where you'd put `single` following Marco's answer).

Another option, maybe a last resort, is to boot from a removable media (like livecd), mount the root partition of your system and either chroot to it or do a dirty job on `/etc/shadow`. By this I mean editing it and removing the password hash field. But it is a dirty (read: **dangerous**) method: Firstly, `/etc/shadow` is a vital security file and an error in its structure can create a security breach or just break a lot of things. To prevent errors, it should only be edited using `vipw -s` command - but this is only possible when you chroot into the system. Other problems could be caused by a conflict/error detected by advanced security mechanisms working on the system. But I haven't used such so far, so cannot tell what those problems might be.

Comment: some dirty job like what??

Comment: I didn't want to write about it in the answer, because of the *dirtyness*: I meant to remove the password hash, then login with no password and set a new one.

Comment: I think it is the best solution... what's dirty about it??

Comment: Editing `/etc/shadow` by hand is dangerous: one can easily mess up the system or maybe even create a conflict in some advanced security mechanism. Ok, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It was long time, I have not used a Ubuntu 12.04 Linux box. I forgot its login id. I tried the following approach and got the login id.

Stop at the Grub boot loader, look for options to edit and to fall back to the command-line.
In  my case for edit it was 'e', and for command line it was 'c'. After pressing 'e' edit key the options for boot and options for command line changes to <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Use any method and drop to boot loader (grub) command shell. Then type ls. It will show the partitions on the disk.

```
#grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
#grub>ls << (the partition of your boot kernel, u can see in the grub list against root option. it will be " root = (hd0,msdos1) >>
```

Otherwise also, you just ls and check /etc/issue or any relevant files for information.

in my case my linux was installed in (hd0,msdos1). Check for the file passwd in etc

```
#ls (hd0,msdos5)/etc/passwd
```

then

```
#cat (hd0,msdos5)/etc/passwd
```

Check the frag end of the file for your user name. Boot normally and use the user name to login.

Comment: Doesn't solve the forgotten password.