# Fix permissions in /usr/lib after chmod on dir

Tags: manjaro

I "accidentally" ran

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 /usr/lib
```

And now many things in my system don't work. Is there a cure for this (Manjaro 17.1) that doesn't involve re-installing my entire system?

Comment: Boot from a pen and chmod file by file with the help of Google. It is guaranteed to be a good pastime; trial and error might keep you entertained until Spring.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but maybe somebody did for lack of research. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194644/80216 "Broken system after chmod -R 644 /"), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56610/80216 "Accidentally set /lib permissions to 644"), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18591/80216 "Did a “sudo go-wrx” on / … oops, broken"), [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/71316/80216 "Ubuntu: sudo find / -type d -exec chmod -Rf a-wr {} \; the user can’t login"), and [this](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/334596/80216 "Is there a way to fix a chmod 777 on an Ubuntu server?").

Answer (score 2):

For a complete and proper fix, you're probably looking at restoring from a backup (you *do* have a backup, right?) or reinstall.  Just doing an ad-hoc `find /usr/lib -type f -exec ls -l "{}" \;  | grep '^-..x..x..x'` on one of my boxen shows a vast scattering of non-directories which *should* be executable on your host.  But not *everything* is meant to be executable.

Comment: Egad, [don’t parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!  Do `find /usr/lib -type f -perm -111` (or, perhaps more usefully, `-perm /111`).  Or, if you have GNU `find`, you can use `-executable`, but that’s of dubious usefulness.  If checks whether the file is executable *by you*, so, if you aren’t root, it will miss files with modes like 744.

Comment: Not to mention not everything should be 0644 or 0755 either. E.g., `4755` for `/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign` on my Debian box. I would guess loss of set-id bits is what broke the system.

Comment: BTW: An alternative you might suggest is to install a *different* machine (or VM) with a fresh install with the same packages. Then copy the permissions over.